# RXJS take 1 if synchronous, else use defaultValue

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I know `activatedRoute` is actually `BehaviourSubject`, but since it's exposed API is observable, I don't want to take chances.

```
activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
    take(1),
).subscribe(query => {  // { page?: '1' | '2' | '3'... }
    this.currentPage = new BehaviourSubject(+(query.page) || 1);
    // Other components actually change this
});

console.log(this.currentPage); // I need this to not be undefined!
```

Does a pipe resembling this exists? `takeSynchonously(1, { page: 1 })`

Comment: With RxJS you should never rely on sync/async behavior and always use Observables.  
In your use-case it seems like you could turn `currentPage` into an instance of `ReplaySubject` and when `queryParams` is ready just push one `next` item with `this.currentPage.next(+(query.page) || 1)`.

Comment: @martin That is my actual implementation, but if one day the observable takes too long to populate all dependant observables will be delayed and that would be very user unfriendly

Comment: Did you mean `startWith`? It does exist.

Comment: @ritaj kind of, but I only want it, if the source does not emit immediately upon subscription (ex if it is behaviour subject it will reply synchronously, thus I don't need fallback values.)

Comment: But it is behavior subject. You can just make your own BehaviorSubject and concat it with queryParams, and subscribe to your own, but that doesn't seem like something one should do.

Comment: I have come up with a sufficent solution, see it below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, it is a combination of `takeUntil`, `timer` and `queueScheduler`.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, Subject, timer, queueScheduler } = rxjs;
const { startWith, defaultIfEmpty, takeUntil, take } = rxjs.operators;

new Subject().pipe(
  take(1),
  takeUntil(timer(1, queueScheduler)),
  defaultIfEmpty(0),
).subscribe(n => console.log('Subject', n));

new ReplaySubject(1).pipe(
  take(1),
  takeUntil(timer(1, queueScheduler)),
  defaultIfEmpty(0),
).subscribe(n => console.log('ReplaySubject', n));

const rs = new ReplaySubject(1);
rs.next(1)
rs.pipe(
  take(1),
  takeUntil(timer(1, queueScheduler)),
  defaultIfEmpty(0),
).subscribe(n => console.log('ReplaySubject (with value)', n));

new BehaviorSubject(5).pipe(
  take(1),
  takeUntil(timer(1, queueScheduler)),
  defaultIfEmpty(0),
).subscribe(n => console.log('BehaviorSubject', n));

console.log('priority')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

**Note:** This must be used in combination with `ReplySubject` or similar. Anything with initial value will be synchronous, but those without it will be processed in the next tick.